# Создать xml файл без декларации

Tags: c#, xml

Необходимо сохранить xml файл на диск без декларации вида `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`. Делаю следующим образом

```
string xml = "<Items>" + innerXml + "</Items>";
xmlFile.LoadXml(xml);
settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment;

XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(patchFile, settings);
xmlFile.Save(xmlWriter);
```

Получаю ошибку вида

> WriteStartDocument не может быть вызван для модуля записи, созданного
>   с помощью ConformanceLevel.Fragment.

Проект на 3.5, использовать `NamespaceHandling.OmitDuplicates` не получится

Comment: у меня работает так: `xmlFile.Save("1.xml");` Если `xmlFile` у вас имеет тип `XmlDocument`. Т.е. вообще без использования `XmlWriterSettings` и `XmlWriter`

Comment: Если `XmlWriter` обязательно нужен, можно писать так: `xmlFile.WriteTo(xmlWriter);` или `xmlFile.WriteContentTo(xmlWriter);`

Comment: М-м-м... Ну так не используйте `ConformanceLevel.Fragment`.